# How to plot certain row and column using panda dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have a very simple data frame but I could not plot a line using a row and a column. Here is an image, I would like to plot a "line" that connects them.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQuio.png)

[image]

[image]

I tried to plot it but x-axis disappeared. And I would like to swap those axes. I could not find an easy way to plot this simple thing.

Comment: To help you, please follow [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) guidelines

Comment: What is the problem? Have you done any research?

Comment: if you read properly, I did my research and plotted second plot. I could not find any solution regarding pandas' data.frame but found in matplotlib. Please check posts carefully before giving negative votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Categories will be x axis, sexonds will be y
plt.plot(data["Categories"], data["Seconds"])
plt.show()
```

Matplotlib generates the axis dynamically, so if you want the labels of the x-axis to appear you'll have to increase the size of your plot.

Comment: The solution is very simple. Thanks, I don't understand why dataframe.plot() is not that simple

Comment: Although the x-axis seems mixed.